# Stocks & Finances

Tags: finance, reference-request

Are there any guides, examples, tutorials how to use finance related functions in Mathematica (except documentation)?

Are there any packages for plotting Japan candles graphs in Mathematica?

Comment: Is [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CandlestickChart.html) what you mean by "Japan candles graphs"?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi , thank you!

Comment: [`https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=stock%20market`](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=stock%20market)

Comment: [This blog](http://jonathankinlay.com/) has many articles using mathematica on finance topics